# Display of highest value of data using two tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i have two tables employee and department with the following data

```
emplyee table
empid    Ename    deptid
1        Ajay      1
2        Vijay     1
3        sanjay    2
4        rajiv     1
5        rohit     2
6        sohit     3
```

department table

```
deptid      deptname
1            HR
2            IT
3            A/C
```

my question is to how to display the dept name which has highest(2nd highest or nth highest) employees in it.
Please help i m beginner in SQl.

Comment: So, can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an inner join and a group by clause, you can then use an order by to order the data how you like

```
SELECT d.deptname,
    COUNT(e.Ename) AS NoOfEmployees
FROM dept d
INNER JOIN emplyee e ON d.deptid = e.deptid
GROUP BY d.deptid
ORDER BY NoOfEmployees
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT T.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpCount DESC) RN 
   FROM
   (
      SELECT d.deptid,d.deptname,count(*) EmpCount
      FROM department d
      JOIN emplyee e on d.deptid=e.deptid
      GROUP BY d.deptid,d.deptname
   ) T  
) T1 WHERE RN=2
```

Here with `RN=2` in the end we will find 2nd biggest department. Change it to `1,2,3,4,...` as you need.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e5d6/7)

Comment: I've never seen SQLFiddle before, that was a nice touch. I used your schema to retest my query as well. Learned something new today, thanks valex.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.deptname
from department d
inner join employee e on e.deptid = d.deptid
group by d.deptname
order by count(d.deptname) desc
```

This will give you the company names only (as requested) in order from highest count to lowest.

You could additionally order by the deptname so that departments with the same count of employees are then listed alphabetically.

If you wanted to have the row number displayed as well (like 1, 2, 3...) then you could add a SQL "Over" clause as well.